# Ajax is not working on my customize component in joomla

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, joomla

I'm having problem on my joomla article which i customize the code with Sourcerer.

Here is some of my example code for the ajax javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showBox1(element) {
        document.getElementById('hideBox1').style.display = "";

        if (element == "")
        {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
            {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "home/matedis/public_html/joomla/Add_Edit_Intake/getuser.php?q=" + element, true);
        xmlhttp.send();

    }

</script>
```

The code for passing the value to the function is here:

```
<?php
// Get default database object
$db = JFactory::getDBO();

// Get a new JDatabaseQuery object
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

// Build the query
$query->select($db->quoteName('campusid'));
$query->from($db->quoteName('campus'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('collegeid') . '=' . $db->quote('1'));

// Set the query for the DB oject to execute
$db->setQuery($query);
// Get the DB object to load the results as a list of objects
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
if ($results) {
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        echo "<label class='option block spacer-t10'>";
        echo "<input type='radio' id ='campusID' name='campusID' value='$result->campusid' onChange='showBox1(this.value)'><span class='radio'></span>";
        echo $result->campusid;
        echo '</label>';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Error';
}
?>
```

Here is my getuser.php code:

```
   <?php

$q = intval($_GET['q']);
define( 'JPATH_BASE', $_SERVER[ 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' ] ); // define JPATH_BASE on the external file
require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'libraries' . DS . 'import.php' ); // framework
require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'configuration.php' ); // config file
$db = JFactory::getDBO();


$sql="SELECT courseid FROM course WHERE campusid = '".$q."'";




// Build the query
$query->select($db->quoteName('courseid'));
$query->from($db->quoteName('course'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('campusid').'='. $db->quote($q)); //This later must change to retrieve id from current user

// Set the query for the DB oject to execute
$db->setQuery($query);// Get the DB object to load the results as a list of objects
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
if($results){
     foreach($results as $result)
     {
        echo $result->courseid;
 } 

}
else{ echo 'Error';}
?>
```

Is there any mistake i had made? Because it does not show up the output i want which i refer the code from here http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp. Sorry if any inconvenience cause because i still new to joomla and php ajax.

Answer (score 0):

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","home/matedis/public_html/joomla/Add_Edit_Intake/getuser.php?q="+element,true);
```

This is real path of public_html? No..

Comment: That is the path of the my php file in my server. Is that a cause of my ajax problem?

Comment: And your server host configured for relative path "home/matedis/public_html/joomla/Add_Edit_Intake/" ? I don't think so, because its fail

Comment: then my getuser.php file should be put in which folder?
I'm currently using cpanel to configure the file manager, the Add_Edit_Intake is the folder i just created inside joomla folder.

Comment: But top point of joomla host located likely in public_html/ directory, and you need set ajax request path like: /joomla/Add_Edit_Intake/getuser.php?q= or /Add_Edit_Intake/getuser.php?q=

Comment: Sorry for bad english :)

Comment: After i change the path to /Add_Edit.... I'm getting error message "Fatal error: Class 'JFactory' not found in /home/matedis/public_html/joomla/Add_Edit_Intake/getuser.php on line 6"

Comment: I had make change on my getuser.php, but no luck...it does not show any result in the output. Is there any code error i make in the javascript ?

Comment: What do you get when you echo JPATH_BASE? It seems to me like you're setting it to your server's web docs folder, maybe the level down to Joomla is missing?